# Shopware 6: sw-inherit-wrapper property currentValue does not update on select

Tags: plugins, vuejs3, shopware6

I've a custom entity `enterprise`, which is assigned to `product.extensions.myPlugin.enterpriseId`.

Now i want to select the `enterprise` within [Shopware Vue-Component `sw-entity-single-select`](https://component-library.shopware.com/components/sw-entity-single-select) wrapped by [`sw-inherit-wrapper`](https://component-library.shopware.com/components/sw-inherit-wrapper):

```
<sw-inherit-wrapper
    v-model="product.extensions.myPlugin.enterpriseId"
    :has-parent="false"
    :inherited-value="null">
    <template #content="{currentValue, updateCurrentValue, isInherited}">
        <sw-entity-single-select
            class="enterprise-name"
            :key="isInherited"
            :value="currentValue"
            entity="enterprise"
            :placeholder="$tc('inputEnterprise.placeholder')"
            show-clearable-button
            allow-entity-creation
            :entity-creation-label="$tc('inputEnterprise.labelCreation')"
            @change="updateCurrentValue"></sw-entity-single-select>
    </template>
</sw-inherit-wrapper>
```

This template ist part of a modal.

**On select** a `enterprise` from given list, the `<sw-entity-single-select__selection-text>` **does not update**.

Step out step in into the template (close and reopen the parent modal), the `enterprise` is set and printed out on the `<sw-entity-single-select__selection-text>`.
So the entity extension was updated but not the property `currentValue` in `<sw-entity-single-select__selection-text>`

As example i follow the [`sw_product_basic_form_manufacturer_field`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/5f506d31ff6478f72efc26c3da35cb04ced70a7a/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/module/sw-product/component/sw-product-basic-form/sw-product-basic-form.html.twig#L36)

**Question:** Why property `currentValue` does **not update in `<sw-entity-single-select>` on select** from its list?

**EDIT #1**
The extension is set in overridden component `sw-product-detail` like this:

```
// sw-product-detail/index.js
...
Component.override('sw-product-detail', {
    ...
    computed: {
        myPluginRepository() {
            return this.repositoryFactory.create('my_plugin');
        },
    }
    watch: {
        product() {
            if(this.product.id) {
                this.__setMyPluginExtension()
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        ...
        __setMyPluginExtension() {
            let extension = this.product.extensions.myPlugin ?? null;
            if(null === extension) {
                extension = 
                this.myPluginRepository.create(Shopware.Context.api);
                extension.enterpriseId = null
            }
            this.product.extensions.myPlugin = extension;
        },        
    }

}
```

Inside the overridden child component `sw-product-detail-base` the modal is loaded.
I think, *the extension is known when* the component is loaded and rendered. I've check it with a debug breakpoint inside the `created()` in the custom component, the extension is known like defined in parent component.
Even more, if i set `extension.enterpriseId` a real default value instead `null` then the enterprise is printed out in `<sw-entity-single-select__selection-text>`, what me indicate, the extension is known.

Btw, i used the `change` method, but i'm looking for my error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best guess without knowing more of the stack would be that `this.product.extensions.myPlugin.enterpriseId` isn't reactive. That would be the case if the property doesn't exists when the product is originally set and it is declared like this:

```js
this.product.extensions.myPlugin = {
    enterpriseId: 'asdf'
};
```

Any further changes to `enterpriseId` would then not be reactive and the view would subsequently not be updated when it changes.

To be safe you could add a `@change` listener to `sw-inherit-wrapper` and update the property reactively:

```js
onEnterpriseIdChange(enterpriseId) {
    if (!this.product.extensions.myPlugin) {
        this.$set(this.product.extensions, 'myPlugin', {});
    }
    if (!this.product.extensions.myPlugin.enterpriseId) {
        this.$set(this.product.extensions.myPlugin, 'enterpriseId', enterpriseId);
    }
}
```

Comment: please take a look of my **Edit #1**

Comment: This declaration is not reactive: `this.product.extensions.myPlugin = extension;`  Use the `$set` method as described and changes will take effect in the view. For a more detailed explanation of reactivity in Vue see [this page](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-in-depth.html).

Answer (score 0):

As addition of @dneustadt answers:

```
...
const extension = this.myPluginRepository.create(Shopware.Context.api);
extension.enterpriseId= null

this.$set(this.product.extensions, 'myPlugin', extension)
...
```

Use the repository `create()` method instead create a simple object because of [required method `entity.getEntityName()` in `changeset-generator.data.js`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/5b0f008b7afe47bea5f397744ce6076e6608e2de/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/core/data/changeset-generator.data.js#L51)